# Rotating cube to show only one side

Tags: opengl, vector, cube

I have a 3D-cube made with opengl which rotates randomly and stopps occasionally showing up to 3 of its sides. I would like to have the cube falling onto one of the sides (x, -x, y, -y, z, -z). I managed it so far to identify the top side of the cube - the one to be shown.
However I'm not able to manipulate the matrix that the cube "falls back".

Let's say I can see side X, Y and Z of the cube and I'd like to rotate the cube so that I can only see the side X. As far as I understand, to achieve this, I need to rotate the cube around the Y and Z axis.

As example I'd like to rotate following matrix on the y and z axis:

[0]=0.90366703   [1]=-0.4241817  [2]=-0.058799066   [3]=0.0     [4]=-0.3704742  [5]=-0.70550096 [6]=-0.6041675   [7]=0.0      [8]=0.21479362   [9]=0.56774914  [10]=-0.7946859   [12]=0.0 [13]=0.0 [14]=0.0 [15]=1.0

This is how I'm trying to define the angle:

```
float[] camera_org = new float[3];    

GL11 gl11 = (GL11) gl;


gl11.glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mdl);

camera_org[0] = -(mdl.get(0) * mdl.get(12) + mdl.get(1) * mdl.get(13) + mdl.get(2) * mdl.get(14));    
camera_org[1] = -(mdl.get(4) * mdl.get(12) + mdl.get(5) * mdl.get(13) + mdl.get(6) * mdl.get(14));   
camera_org[2] = -(mdl.get(8) * mdl.get(12) + mdl.get(9) * mdl.get(13) + mdl.get(10) * mdl.get(14));

   Log.i("CubeOrientation", camera_org[0]  + "  " +  camera_org[1] + "  " + camera_org[2]
   + "  "+ 90 / 6 * camera_org[0]  + "°  " + 90 / 6 *  camera_org[1] + "°  " + 90 / 6 * camera_org[2] + "°");


 float angle_x = camera_org[0] < 0 ? 90 / 6 * camera_org[0] : -90 / 6 * camera_org[0];
 float angle_y = camera_org[1] < 0 ? 90 / 6 * camera_org[1] : -90 / 6 * camera_org[1];
 float angle_z = camera_org[2] < 0 ? 90 / 6 * camera_org[2] : -90 / 6 * camera_org[2];
 angle_x = angle_x < 0 ? angle_x + 90 : angle_x - 90;
 angle_y = angle_y < 0 ? angle_y + 90 : angle_y - 90;
 angle_z = angle_z < 0 ? angle_z + 90 : angle_z - 90;
```

This is how I'm trying to make the calculations:

```
 float x1 = matrix[0];
 float y1 = matrix[1];
 float z1 = matrix[2];

 float x2 = matrix[4];
 float y2 = matrix[5];
 float z2 = matrix[6];

 float x3 = matrix[8];
 float y3 = matrix[9];
 float z3 = matrix[10];


 float[] xz1 = rotateY(angle_y, x1, z1);
 float[] xz2 = rotateY(angle_y, x2, z2);
 float[] xz3 = rotateY(angle_y, x3, z3);

 matrix[0] = xz1[0]; // x
 x1 = xz1[0];
 matrix[2] = xz1[1]; // z

 matrix[4] = xz2[0]; // x
 x2 = xz2[0];
 matrix[6] = xz2[1]; // z

 matrix[8] = xz3[0]; // x
 x3 = xz3[0];
 matrix[10] = xz3[1]; // z


 float[] xy1 = rotateZ(angle_z, x1, y1);
 float[] xy2 = rotateZ(angle_z, x2, y2);
 float[] xy3 = rotateZ(angle_z, x3, y3);


 matrix[0] = xy1[0]; // x
 matrix[1] = xy1[1]; // y

 matrix[4] = xy2[0]; // x
 matrix[5] = xy2[1]; // y

 matrix[8] = xy3[0]; // x
 matrix[9] = xy3[1]; // y
```

And this is how I'm trying to calculate the rotations:

```
/**
 * Rotate X.
 * 
 * @param angle_x
 * @param y
 * @param z
 * @return [0] = y, [1] = z
 */
private float[] rotateX(float angle_x, float y, float z)
{
    float[] res = new float[2];

    res[0] = (float) (y * Math.cos(angle_x) - z * Math.sin(angle_x));
    res[1] = (float) (y * Math.sin(angle_x) + z * Math.cos(angle_x));

    return res;
}

/**
 * Rotate Y.
 * 
 * @param angle_y
 * @param x
 * @param z
 * @return [0] = x, [1] = z
 */
private float[] rotateY(float angle_y, float x, float z)
{
    float[] res = new float[2];

    res[0] = (float) (x * Math.cos(angle_y) + z * Math.sin(angle_y));
    res[1] = (float) (-x * Math.sin(angle_y) + z * Math.cos(angle_y));

    return res;
}

/**
 * Rotate Z.
 * 
 * @param angle_z
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @return [0] = x, [1] = y
 */
private float[] rotateZ(float angle_z, float x, float y)
{
    float[] res = new float[2];

    res[0] = (float) (x * Math.cos(angle_z) - y * Math.sin(angle_z));
    res[1] = (float) (y * Math.cos(angle_z) + x * Math.sin(angle_z));

    return res;
}
```

Has anyone done something similar sometime or could help me out?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Define the local vector v that represents the side that you want to see.  For example, if you want to see the negative X axis, then v should be <-1,0,0>.

If the current rotation of your cube relative to the world is the rotation matrix M, then multiplying M*v will give you the direction that the face is facing relative to the world.  What you want is to apply another matrix N that rotates the face to point toward you, which would typically be the positive Z axis:

```
N*M*v = <0,0,1>
```

You want N to be a rotation of a particular angle about a particular axis.  The axis will be the cross product of the direction it is facing and the direction you want it to face:

```
axis=cross(M*v,<0,0,1>)/abs(cross(M*v,<0,0,1>))
```

The sine and cosine of the angle can be determined

```
cos_angle=dot(M*v,<0,0,1>)
sin_angle=abs(cross(M*v,<0,0,1>))
```

Angle is then

```
atan2(sin_angle,cos_angle)
```

Your new rotation matrix M' is then simply

```
M' = N*M
```